# Reference JS file in Other JS File and Intellisense

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I've been learning JQuery and I am writing my custom jquery codes in Custom.js file. Actually what I am trying to do is, activate intellisense for Jquery in visual studio but it's not working and I want intellisense to also work in custom.js file where actually I'm writing my custom logic and codes.

I thought it could be solved by reference jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js in custom.js.

I've downloaded and installed update pack of jquery for visual studio 2008 on my computer.

So what should I do to activate intellisense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, when using Visual Studio 2008, install hotfix [KB958502](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502). Second, download the vsdoc file to the same folder as the original jQuery.js file, and make sure that **file names match**, i.e. if original file name is *jquery-1.3.2.js*, then the vsdoc file should be named *jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js* (notice: not *vsdoc2.js*); if you're using the min version of the file, adjust the name accordingly. Third, do not include the vsdoc file in the project (it's enough for the file to be in the same folder). Finally, to enable IntelliSense in custom JavaScript files, add the following line at the top of the JavaScript file (enter the correct path):

```
/// <reference path="path-to-vsdoc-file" />
```

Bonus: To refresh JavaScript IntelliSense, press Ctrl+Shift+J.

Comment: Don't know about VS 2008, but in VS 2010 I just need to drag the vsdoc file into the custom file and it adds something like /// <reference path="jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" /> to the custom file.